# Solve with conditions on the coefficients

Tags: equation-solving

I have a cubic function to solve, but I would like to set the conditions for some coefficients to be positive and real. And I want only a positive real root.

This is the code I have so far.

```
Solve[(-Subscript[c, a]^3)*(1 + Subscript[d, 0]^2)^2*
         Subscript[d, a] - Subscript[c, 0]^2*Subscript[c, a]*
         (6*Subscript[d, 0] + 4*Subscript[d, 0]^3 - 
            (3 + Subscript[d, 0]^2)*Subscript[d, a])*
         (1 + Subscript[d, a]^2) - Subscript[c, 0]*
         Subscript[c, a]^2*Subscript[d, 0]*
         (1 + Subscript[d, 0]^2)*(3 + 2*Subscript[d, 0]*
              Subscript[d, a] + Subscript[d, a]^2) + 
       Subscript[c, 0]^3*(1 + Subscript[d, a]^2)*
         (2*Subscript[d, a] + Subscript[d, 0]*
              (-3 - 2*Subscript[d, 0]*Subscript[d, a] + 
                 Subscript[d, a]^2)) == 0, Subscript[c, a]]
```

How should I modify it to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally best to avoid `Subscript` where possible, as they can lead to some very awkward errors when pattern substitution automatically replaces one or more of their components.

The straightforward way of doing this is to add the constraints to the `Solve` command directly:

```
eqn = -ca^3 (1 + d0^2)^2 da - 
    c0^2 ca (6 d0 + 4 d0^3 - (3 + d0^2) da) (1 + da^2) - 
    c0 ca^2 d0 (1 + d0^2) (3 + 2 d0 da + da^2) + 
    c0^3 (1 + da^2) (2 da + d0 (-3 - 2 d0 da + da^2)) == 0;

Solve[{eqn, ca>0, c0>0, d0>0, da>0}, ca]
```

This will give a complicated `Root` expression inside of a `ConditionalExpression`, meaning that there are places where the solution is valid but the constraints are not met. So long as the condition of the `ConditionalExpression` is met though, all of the coefficients should be positive. Further simplification would depend on what form you want the output in, see `Root` objects in the documentation.

Note that variables involved in ordering operations (`>`) are automatically assumed real by *Mathematica*.

Comment: Thank you sir. That's so helpful